# How to increase page views

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, views

My questions tend to get very few views, and even less answers (obviously).

One problem, is I always spend hours trying to solve the problem, and typically only post if I run into a true corner case, but even still the views are very low.

I may post too much information.

Any advice?

Comment: Your [latest question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17031498/102937) is off-topic.

Comment: as in wrong site?

Comment: [Next question](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31274/discussion-between-kiwiwings-and-ajon) is NaRQ (self-deleted).

Comment: Next question was highly localized.  You moved it to chat, but ultimately solved the problem yourself.

Comment: The question after that has an accepted answer on it.

Comment: Twitter/Facebook/Google+

Answer (score 2):

Well it's simple. If your questions are rare cases, boderline off-topic or boderline too localized :

> only post if I run into a true corner case

Chances are you won't have many users looking at this question since they don't need an answer to that and won't be searching for this.
**Don't get me wrong !** It's **required** that you do your research before posting  that but there is not magic trick.

Easy questions that come up often are likely to get more views. Of course, you will have to be the first one to ask it and since the site has been up since 2009 or so, chances are it has already been asked.

Two guidelines that *might* help

- Think of a good, clear, precise title
- Give it some time. Most overly seen questions have been here for four years or so.